# How to retrieve the thread id from a boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I want to be able to identify threads by a simple id when logging so that it is easy to trace the execution of a single thread.  With windows using the API `GetCurrentThreadId()` can achieve what I want.  In `boost::thread` there is a method `get_id()` but this doesn't represent an integral value like an integer.  This object does have a thread_data member which contains an id which seems to be what I want but the data member is private so can't be accessed.

What is the boost way to access the thread id for display or identification purposes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boost includes an `operator<<(std::ostream&, const boost::thread::id&)` overload that can be used to write a thread id to a stream (actually, the overload is a template and will work with any specialization of `std::basic_ostream`, not just `std::ostream`).

The result of printing the id is likely platform-specific, since different platforms may use different internal representations for thread identifiers.

Comment: so as a parameter to a function I would pass the boost::thread::id to be used with an output stream operator?  This sounds close except what if you want the value to be usable without streams or stream operators?

Comment: using boost::this_thread::get_id() from within the threads worker function actually worked out with the sprintf_s style formatting no parameter needed.

Answer (score 53):

Too late, but for users looking for an answer, boost allows to consult the thread id as you said, simply calling the following method:

```
boost::this_thread::get_id()
```

This method returns a internal id type from boost, that is not numeric as you want. But you can easily convert this number to, for example, an unsigned long taking into account that the id has as hexadecimal representation. This little function will do de Job:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

unsigned long getThreadId(){
    std::string threadId = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(boost::this_thread::get_id());
    unsigned long threadNumber = 0;
    sscanf(threadId.c_str(), "%lx", &threadNumber);
    return threadNumber;
}

void drawThreadId(){
    std::cout << getThreadId() << std::endl;
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
}

int main() {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        boost::thread thread = boost::thread(drawThreadId);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will return something like this:

```
4491075584
4491612160
4492148736
4492685312
4493221888
4493758464
4494295040
4494831616
4495368192
4495904768
```

Do not forget link with boost_thread and boost_system.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I fetch ID from thread object? (`boost::thread mythread`)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the member function `boost::thread::native_handle()`.  It returns a type `native_handle_type` which is an implementation defined alias for a native thread identifier, which can then be used with native thread API functions.

Comment: While useful to know all I need is the thread id. The primary reason for using boost::thread is to avoid OS specific calls in my case.

Comment: @AJG85: ... and `nativehandle()` will propvide you with *exactly* such a unique identifier, so what is the problem? You don't have to use it for anything else; that was merely an explanation of what the value represents; it is in fact *exactly* what you'd get from `GetCurrentThreadId()`.  Importantly this identifier will be the same as that displayed in the *threads* window of the debugger, so knowing its value may help multi-threaded debugging.

Comment: Good point. Just because it can be used for native calls doesn't mean that is the only thing it is for.  Also I believe it's equivalent to the handle you would get from GetCurrentThread() as opposed to the integer id returned by GetCurrentThreadId().

Comment: Thanks for this; may not have been the best answer for the posted question, but it helped me =]